# Reading a bunch of files and reorganizing them

Tags: python

I have a bunch of files which have been resulted from Fortran and they are text format and named "Configuration". I have to 1-read all of them separately 2-Remove 3 first columns and 3-add 3 new columns which are read from another text file.

but it did not work then I tried to use `for` loop, it was also useless and I do not know how to solve this problem(Both tries have been shown below). Could you please help me. Thanks all in advance

```py
import numpy as np
import os 
l = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if f.startswith('config')]

for i, d in enumerate(l):
    a = np.loadtxt(d)
    num = os.path.splitext(d)[0]
    a = np.delete(a,1,0)
b = np.savetxt(a)
```

```
with open([f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if f.startswith('config')],) as csvfile:
    input = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in input:
....
```

Comment: where's the relation to machine learning? Also, I think `np.savetxt` is missing a [filename input](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) in your code.

Comment: I want to use them as an input to teach the machine then after training and pattern recognition I wanna predict

Comment: @HosseinAmini could you please provide a minimal (not working) example including the file names, the expected result and the actual result? I'm having difficulties understanding the problem.

Comment: @MrFuppes it means that I asked in a wrong place?

Comment: it's alright! also, I think your upper code snippet is fine, just put `np.savetxt(a)` inside the `for loop` and provide it with a filename.

Comment: @konstantin let's get started from the beginning, I have 100 files for a different time step which have named "file_0" to "file_100" and I want to use them for training machine but the problem is this each of which has 3 unuseful columns that should be deleted from tables. Now I used codes above to do this but I could not since I got an error of defining names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you could do is modify your code a bit, it should work like this:

```
import os
import numpy as np

loc ='D:/' # replace with where your files are...
files = [os.path.join(loc, f) for f in os.listdir(loc) if f.startswith('config')]

for file in files:
    a = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter=',')
    a = np.delete(a, 1, 0)
    # just an example fname modification; to avoid overwrite:
    _ = np.savetxt(str(file).replace('config', 'modified_config'), a)
```

also, it might be useful to provide `np.savetxt` with a fmt string, check [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

Comment: Now it took error from the **files** which has been defined `[loc/f for f in os.listdir(loc) if f.startswith('config')]`. it said _[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\hossein\\Desktop\\backup\\new sim\\new with param\\r'_ while it has been already read by **loc** command.

Comment: so `os.listdir(loc)` throws the error? did you verify the path? Note that `loc/f` notation will only work if you use the `Path` function from the `pathlib` module. otherwise, you could use `os.path.join(loc, f)`. Made an edit to show that option.

Comment: unfortunately, I still have a problem with reading them. I think another problem is related to for loop, the counter of for should be the code format of this:
for configuration_0 to configuration_101:
      a = [command of converting to save text file for each file]
      b = [saving each a with a specific name]

Comment: concerning the `for loop`, `for item in iterable` is common Python syntax (if you need the index, use `enumerate`). So your problem must be related to finding the files on your device. The code works fine if I put some dummy files on my `D:/` drive, e.g. `D:/config1.txt`. If `files` does not contain anything, something must be wrong with the path you provided, e.g. missing path separator `/` or there simply are no matching filenames in the designated location.